# Nestjs can't connect to mongo while running in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, nestjs, prisma

I have nestjs application with prisma mongodb setup. Nestjs connects well to dockerized mongo while running itself (nestjs) outside docker.

But when I try to run nestjs inside docker, it can't connect to mongo.

docker-compose.yml

```js
version: '3.8'

# For connection urls to the following instances, see
# https://github.com/prisma/prisma/blob/main/TESTING.md#environment-variables
services:
  # Replica Set (required for Prisma Client)
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/mongo.Dockerfile
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
      MONGO_REPLICA_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      MONGO_REPLICA_PORT: 27018
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '27018:27018'
  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/app.Dockerfile
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mongodb://root:prisma@mongo:27018/bookmeon?authSource=admin
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

mongo.Dockerfile:

```js
###################
# MONGO container - for replication
###################

FROM mongo:4 As mongo

# we take over the default & start mongo in replica set mode in a background task
ENTRYPOINT mongod --port $MONGO_REPLICA_PORT --replSet rs0 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 & MONGOD_PID=$!; \
# we prepare the replica set with a single node and prepare the root user config
INIT_REPL_CMD="rs.initiate({ _id: 'rs0', members: [{ _id: 0, host: '$MONGO_REPLICA_HOST:$MONGO_REPLICA_PORT' }] })"; \
INIT_USER_CMD="db.getUser('$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME') || db.createUser({ user: '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME', pwd: '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD', roles: [ 'root' ] })"; \
# we wait for the replica set to be ready and then submit the commands just above
until (mongo admin --port $MONGO_REPLICA_PORT --eval "$INIT_REPL_CMD && $INIT_USER_CMD"); do sleep 1; done; \
# we are done but we keep the container by waiting on signals from the mongo task
echo "REPLICA SET ONLINE"; wait $MONGOD_PID;
```

app.Dockerfile:

```js
###################
# base
###################

#FROM node:20.5.1-alpine3.18 As base
FROM node:20.5.1-alpine3.18 As base
RUN apk add openssl1.1-compat
RUN apk add musl

RUN npm i -g pnpm

###################
# deps install
###################

FROM base As deps

WORKDIR /my

COPY --chown=node:node ./package.json .

RUN pnpm i

###################
# build
###################

FROM base As build

WORKDIR /my

COPY --chown=node:node --from=deps ./my/. .
COPY --chown=node:node ./tsconfig* .
COPY --chown=node:node ./webpack.js .

COPY --chown=node:node ./prisma ./prisma
COPY --chown=node:node ./src ./src
COPY --chown=node:node ./aps ./aps

ARG DATABASE_URL="mongodb://root:prisma@mongo:27018/bookmeon?authSource=admin"

RUN pnpm exec prisma generate
RUN pnpm run build

USER node

CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

.env:

```js
DATABASE_URL="mongodb://root:prisma@mongo:27018/bookmeon?authSource=admin"

MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=prisma
MONGO_REPLICA_HOST=127.0.0.1
MONGO_REPLICA_PORT=27018

NODE_ENV=staging
FORCE_WWW=0
FORCE_TLS=0
```

Error i get in dockerized nestjs:

```js
book_me_on-web-1  | PrismaClientInitializationError: Raw query failed. Code: `unknown`. Message: `Server selection timeout: No available servers. Topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [ { Address: 127.0.0.1:27018, Type: Unknown, Error: Connection refused (os error 111) }, ] }`
book_me_on-web-1  |     at r (/my/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@5.0.0_prisma@5.0.0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:103:2766)
book_me_on-web-1  |     at async Proxy.onModuleInit (/my/dist/prisma.service.js:14:9)
book_me_on-web-1  |     at async Promise.all (index 0)
book_me_on-web-1  |     at async callModuleInitHook (/my/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.0.0_@nestjs+common@10.0.0_@nestjs+platform-express@10.0.0_reflect-metadata@0.1.13_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-module-init.hook.js:43:5)
book_me_on-web-1  |     at async NestApplication.callInitHook (/my/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.0.0_@nestjs+common@10.0.0_@nestjs+platform-express@10.0.0_reflect-metadata@0.1.13_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:223:13)
book_me_on-web-1  |     at async NestApplication.init (/my/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.0.0_@nestjs+common@10.0.0_@nestjs+platform-express@10.0.0_reflect-metadata@0.1.13_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:97:9)
book_me_on-web-1  |     at async NestApplication.listen (/my/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.0.0_@nestjs+common@10.0.0_@nestjs+platform-express@10.0.0_reflect-metadata@0.1.13_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:166:33)
book_me_on-web-1  |     at async bootstrap (/my/dist/main.js:21:5) {
book_me_on-web-1  |   clientVersion: '5.0.0',
book_me_on-web-1  |   errorCode: 'P2010'
book_me_on-web-1  | }
book_me_on-web-1  | 
book_me_on-web-1  | Node.js v20.5.1
```

UPDATE:

I tried to create small docker container which logs some runtime envs (and changed MONGO_REPLICA_HOST to 172.19.0.2 manually);

```js
FROM node:20.5.1-alpine3.18 as base

# ping $MONGO_REPLICA_HOST:$MONGO_REPLICA_PORT; \

ENTRYPOINT echo $NODE_ENV; \
sleep 5s & PID=$!; \
echo $MONGO_REPLICA_PORT; \
echo $MONGO_REPLICA_HOST; \
ping "mongo":$MONGO_REPLICA_PORT; \
echo "Done"; \
echo "Process ID" + PID;
```

As a result in resulting log i see that nestjs tries to connect to
172.19.0.2:27018, while in this new test container I see that mongo is pinged by 172.19.0.3:27018 (using mongo host name)

```js
web      | PrismaClientInitializationError: Raw query failed. Code: `unknown`. Message: `Server selection timeout: No available servers. Topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [ { Address: 172.19.0.2:27018, Type: Unknown, Error: Connection refused (os error 111) }, ] }`
```

So looks like mongo runs on a bit another ip address than I start it and nestjs tries to connect to wrong place in docker.

Comment: You need to wait a few seconds after running `rs.initiate()`. And you may connect with `readPreference=primaryPreferred` to ensure that you always switch to PRIMARY.

Comment: How can I do that? I can't understand how to pass this option to mongo. Should it be mongo cli -- parameter? or Should i use rs.reconfig()

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue about docker, I do not go along with every hype.

Comment: Heh, I'm with you. I'm having hard time with it the second day as I tried to use it.

Answer (score 0):

When running within Docker, your localhost (127.0.0.1) is not visible to Docker network - you need to set your env variable `MONGO_REPLICA_HOST` to `mongo` (the name of the service you have defined in your docker-compose), that way Docker will understand which service you are pointing to and will automatically set the host value

Comment: Tx, Tried, but didn't help. 
The thing is that I can connect to mongo service started in docker locally (outside docker) but nestjs in docker still can't

Comment: Actually i have found all localhost/127.0.0.1 entries in my project and replaced them with mongo, then di docker-compose build, docker-compose up, scratch test container pings mongo by 172... address and nest still tries to connect to 127..., looks like problem is in how prisma client is generated.

Comment: May be problem is related somehow to "--bind_ip 0.0.0.0"? If I remove it, nestjs outside of docker can't connect as well.

Comment: In your docker-compose for Mongo service you are setting bot `environment` and `env_file` for env values. docker-compose takes precedence and uses values from `environment` (overrides what you have in env_file) so it should be safe to remove/comment out MONGO_REPLICA_HOST and MONGO_REPLICA_PORT from docker-compose environment configuration

Comment: Yeah,  tx, I agree, Added it just to make sure that even if I override it nothing works (

Answer (score 0):

I was sure that it's something with prisma client generation IP address substitution, but turned out it was my docker daemon. I have completely reinstalled docker daemon (removed all images/containers as well) and reinstalled all images, recreated containers again.

And with no changes in dockerfiles, dockercompose or prisma scheme nestjs starts well now. Thanks to everyone!